# How to set autolayout constraint using visual language to superview with default constant and non-default priority

Tags: cocoa-touch, autolayout

In visual format language a string `H:|-[view]-|` means: have the standard margins to superview.

If I want these standard margins to have a priority less than the default, I would want to write `H:|-@750-[view]-@750-|` but that does not work, leaving me the only possibility to write an explicit value for the margin (`H:|-8@750-[view]-8@750-|`), which I do not want to do (as I have to hard code this margin now).

Is there a way to specify standard margins with a different priority than the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(...nope, I don't see any mention of a term representing standard margin in the [VFL documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html) either.)

What you can do, is generate standard margin constraints, then pick them out from the results of `+constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:` and then change their priority *before* activating and adding them, as you cannot change the priority between required and optional once the constraints are active (though you can still change priority between different optional priority values).